# How to upload a JPG to facebook with the caption pre-embedded?

Tags: automation, jpeg, upload, facebook, exif

What field do I have to put my caption into to have it show up on Facebook pre-captioned?

I've been living on generating FBCMD scripts for years, but the developer has retired the project as of the latest API changes.

I've uploaded thousands of photos with the captions already written. It's in my own proprietary system. I wrote the bridge between my stuff and FBCMD, but now that FBCMD is gone, it's looking like I will have to embed my info directly into the JPG.

After an hour of experimentation... I've gotten nowhere.

Comment: did you try the IPTC Caption field?

Comment: I gave it a go, but apparently Facebook stopped doing that because people screamed 'privacy'.